# Removing the middle elements from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

My task is design an array list method that checks to see whether the length of the arraylist is odd or even. I can't figure out what I need to do once I divided the length by 2 to check if odd or even but I don't know what to do from here. Once found I need to remove the elements from the array which would decrease the size I assume.

Answer (score 7):

Checking if a value is odd or even is actually really simple. We can use the [modulus operator](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/).

**Example**

```
List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

int size = objects.size();

if(size % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("This is an even sized list.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("This is an odd sized list.");
}
```

**How Modulo works**

The `%` operator is designed to get *the remainder from division*. For example:

```
int num = 15;

int remainder = num % 3;
```

`remainder` is equal to `0`, because you can divide 15 by 3 exactly, with 0 remainder.

```
int num = 10;
int remainder = num % 3;
```

Now, `remainder` is equal to `1`, because you can get `3` into `10` 3 times, with 1 left over. It's what's left over that is returned.

Comment: +1. A small correction `This is an even number` should be `This is an even list`  :)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply check

```
if(yourArrayLength %2 ==0) {
    //even
}else{
   //odd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example, that may help you

```
  ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    if((list.size())%2==0)
    {
        System.out.println("size is even");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("size is odd");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the module operator, like this:

```
var numeros = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
var oddEven = numeros.length % 2;
if(oddEven == 1){
    $('html').append('Number odd');
} else {
    $('html').append('Number even');
}
```

The residual number is equal to 1 if it is odd number, otherwise it is an even number.

I hope it works for you.

http://codepen.io/ycisne/pen/Juxmk

Comment: sorry @christopher, my mistake, but he could apply the module operator method